# The function does not return a proper array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, return

The first `console.log` displays the array correctly but when I call it from outside it displays a pair of empty curly braces.

```
var tofind = function (){
    var userss = [];
    user.find(function (err, people) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log("asad");

        var parsed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(people));
        userss = parsed;
        console.log(userss);  
        //displays correctly
    return userss;
    });
}   
console.log(new tofind());
//displays empty pair of curly braces {}
```

Comment: Ponder this: what is it exactly that you are printing out on the last line?

Comment: why print `new tofind()`? your array or variable will initialize value again, or reset. try console.log(tofind()); or moved the var userss = [];

Comment: console.log(tofind()); prints undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your `tofind` function doesn't explicitly return anything. Which means that what you are outputting in the console is the instance of `tofind` itself.

You can either add a public function to the instance scope:

```
var tofind = function() {

  var userss = [];
  ...

  this.getUserss = function() { return userss };
}

console.log( (new tofind()).getUserss() );
```

Or return the userss in the end of the tofind function.

```
var tofind = function() {

  var userss = [];
  ...

  return userss;
}
```

Comment: still returns an empty array [] only

Comment: I don't know what the user.find does, but if it is async have you allowed it to execute before doing the console log?

Comment: oh yes you are right. the empty object is printed first and then the method is invoked. what shall i do?

Comment: I normally use promises to solve that issue, take a look at Q.js https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: i dont know how to use it..can u give me some beginner level guidelines over it.